# How do I create a hitbox for a semi-circle?

Tags: java, collision-detection, pixel

I want to collide a rectangle with a semi-circle that comes rotating. A rectangular hitbox for the semi-circle, of course, is not appropriate as the side of the rectangular hitbox on the round side of the semi-circle will touch other targets before the semi-circle touches the targets. I am not inclined to use pixel collision detection as the two images are large.

I am thinking of using stripes of narrow hitbox rectangles of varying heights that approximately cover the contours of the semi-circle. How well would this work?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you are doing collision detection, so I will just assume parametric equations and you can easily test for collisions between basic shapes.

If you think of a semi-circle as a circle missing a triangular element, then this is easy.

```
if (collide(rect, circle) && !collide(rect, triangle)) {
    // then collision semi-circle
}
```

Use an isosceles triangle. The tip of the triangle is the center of the circle. The height of the triangle is the radius of the circle. The angle is based on what is missing from the circle.

Comment: If the circle is less than half round, then create a triangle from the wedge of the circle, and you have collision when the rectangle intersects both the triangle and the circle.

Comment: Thaks Mike. The idea had struck me before, but I never pursued it.

Comment: In the game, I am is firing a bullet into a square pocket cut out of the edge of a rotating ball image. That is, a rotating circular ball image has one square groove on its edge (cut out from the edge) and the bullet I shoot at it has to land at the groove (if the bullet misses the groove and hits the circular edge of the ball, the game is over). I have used an Ellipse2D hitbox/hitcircle for the ball and a slender rectangular hitbox with the width of the groove and the length of the diameter of the circle that runs from the groove along the diameter. The problem is the hitbox doesn't rotate.

Comment: I guess I don't understand why the hit box not rotating is an issue. The circle rotates, but it is a circle so the math is the same whether it rotates or not. So I would treat both as if they don't rotate.